# Style first character in NavigationBar title in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, fonts, navigationbar

I'm trying to change the first characters font color in SwiftUI like this

[image: Image showing style wanted]

But I'm getting the warning saying `Only unstyled text can be used with navigationTitle(_:)` when I run the app, and the text shows up as black. Since I don't want to change the whole font - changing the font color of the navigationBar is not an option. Is the only way to go to make a custom NavigationBar?

The app has iOS 14 as minimum requirements.

This is my current try for a solution... but then the whole title turns black, since styled text isn't allowed.

```
let titleToSet = (Text("M").foregroundColor(Color.red) + Text("y page")

NavigationView {
            contentView()
            .navigationTitle(titleToSet)
}
```

Comment: This needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please show sufficient code to run and show this error.

Comment: Some code would help, as mentioned in the comment above. Also, it doesn't even look like a native `NavigationView` & title to me, but maybe it's because of the font?

Comment: I have updated the question with some code and my current try for a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can place any kind of view you want in the `.toolbar`. It doesn't have to be a button. You can roll your own title view. So, that just leaves the view itself. If you want to simply make the first letter red, then the simplest way of creating this view is by concatenating your text, after you remove the first letter from the remaining title text.

```
struct ToolBarStyledText: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    TitleView("My page")
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                }
            }
    }
}

struct TitleView: View {
    let firstLetter: String
    let remainingText: String
    
    init(_ title: String) {
        var text = title
        if !text.isEmpty {
            firstLetter = String(text.removeFirst())
            remainingText = text
        } else {
            firstLetter = ""
            remainingText = ""
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(firstLetter).foregroundColor(.red).bold() + Text(remainingText).bold()
    }
}
```

Comment: This works really well... unfortunately you loose the possibility to use the large navigation title that moves upon scroll :(

Comment: You are going to have to choose your compromise. However, this is an appropriate answer to the question asked.